# SharePoint 2010 Not Showing Full Breadcrumb and Home Logo Not Working

Tags: sharepoint

I'm playing around trying to get the breadcrumbs working in my new 2010 site to display the complete path from the root to where ever the user navigates.  At the moment when I navigate to a subsite the breadcrumb only shows the current site down so you can't easily get back to the main home page.  I've tried all the settings under navigation in the site settings but nothing seems to work!  Anyone know how to get this working?

Also I'm using SPLinkButton (see below) in the master page to place a clickable logo at the top so users can get back to the site root but this always renders a link to the current site and not the root.  Is there anyway to get this working?  I'm just about to resort to hardcoding a href but this seems a like a poor hack.

```
<SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/" id="onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic2X">
<SharePoint:SiteLogoImage name="onetidHeadbnnr0" id="onetidHeadbnnr2" LogoImageUrl="/_layouts/1033/images/BLP/logo_168x56.gif" runat="server"/></SharePoint:SPLinkButton>
```

The collection has a mixture of published and non published sites so not sure if this causes a problem but I'm sure this sort of thing should be simple.

Thanks in advance!

Dan

Answer (score 0):

On the breadcrumb issue - I'm currently working on the same problem.  I don't have a good answer for you there, except most things I've read involve implementing custom code.  Here's a [couple](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-1-Implementing_Consistent_Navigation_across_Site_Collections.aspx) of [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019150/extending-sharepoint-breadcrumbs-across-multiple-site-collections) on the topic.

On the logo issue - in your `SPLinkButton`, just change `"~site/"` to `"/"` (so you'd have `NavigateURL="/"`) and that should get you back to the root.

Good luck!

Comment: Cool thanks for the info, it appears to be a pain to get the breadcrumbs working correctly from looking around.

For the navigation "/" didn't work for me as it takes you right back to the server root and it only works if I use "/sites/rootsite" so I'll stick with that.

Cheers